Prove that a function doesn't have a horizontal asymptote

Suppose that
$$
f'(x) = \frac{x^2+8x}{x^2+8}
$$
with a horizontal asymptote $y=1$. Prove that $f(x)$ doesn't have a horizontal asymptote.

One of my classmates suggested that if the function $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote, then its slope must approach $0$. But $f'(x) \to 1$; thus $f(x)$ doesn't have a horizontal asymptote.
But the teacher said that this explanation wouldn't get full points if it were on the test. Any better explanations? (We haven't learned integrals and limits yet. Only the fact that limits are used with the horizontal asymptote).

You need integration to get f(x), from where you can find out if any asymptotes exist or not

Do you know about the Mean Value Theorem?

Honestly though, I don't find any mistake in the reasoning. Tangent of the function must tend to be zero if limit tends to infinity in order to order to for it to have a horizontal asymptote. It's evident that it does not , as it tends to be 1. So I think it's a good reasoning. I wonder what a counter example would be

hint
Assume, it has.
So,
$$\exists a\in R :\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x)-a)=0$$
$\implies$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=0$$
$\implies$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(C_x)=0$$
with MVT and $x<C_x<x+1$,
but
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(C_x)=1$$
